# how to add validation on date overlaps in grails

Tags: grails

I have a domain class where i have a field where there are two dates namely start date and stop date. I have mysql database linked with my application. While entering details in webpage, i need to make sure that the date given does not overlap with older enteries in the database.

My domain class is defined below:

class Assigned {

```
String assignedTo = " "
Date assignedDate
Date expiryDate
String ownedBy
String additionalInformation = " "

static constraints = {
    assignedTo()
    assignedDate()
    expiryDate()
    ownedBy()
    additionalInformation()    
}
```

}

when i press create in the view, i need to validate that no other things overlap with the current dates i have given.

please help. Thanking you in advance..

Comment: What do you mean by overlap ? Do you want to test that assignedDate is lower than expiryDate ?

Comment: I have an inventory and the above class is to assign the inventory to someone. So while i give a assigned date and expiry date i need to make sure that the inventory is not already assigned to someone else on that date. So i need to check with the previous assigned objects from database.

Comment: The answer of sverma is good. You can do that easily with a 'where query' or with a 'validator'. You'll find all the details you need in the documentation. Tell me if you need more details.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the period between the given start and end date with the other entries.

Write a method that check for each stored period 
- if the start date is greater equals the stored start date 
AND 
- if the start date is less equals the stored end date

Do this also for the end date.

In the controller call the method from the save/update method. If start or end date overlap with another period you create a validation failed message + redirect to the create/edit view.